# How to display item name after axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I try to display the item name (here the item is an ingredient) after getting it by an axios request. I don't understand what I need to do to use to "return" the item name.

Axios return the name of the item without any problem so I tried to display it with `return <p>{response.data.name}</p>` but nothing is displayed.

I juste have this message : "Expected to return a value in arrow function"

ListIng is called (props.recipe.ing_list = ["whateverid", "whateverid"]) :

`<td><ListIng list={props.recipe.ing_list} /></td>`

and I try this to display the name of the item :

```
    const ListIng = props => (
        props.list.map((item) => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:4000/ingredient/' + item)
            .then(response => {
                return <p>{response.data.name}</p>
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
        })
    )
```

*It's my first post so if there is anything I can improve, don't hesitate to tell me ;-)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually api calls should be inside componentDidMount() lifecycle method.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


const ListIng extends Component {
    state={name:null};

    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.list.map((item) => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:4000/ingredient/' + item)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({name:response.data.name});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
        })
    }   

    render() {
    return(
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
    );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning value from `.then` callback function. Returned value will be passed to nest `.then` if any, but will not be used as return value from functional component.

As you're using async call, you should use state, to make React know, that data is ready and component should be re-rendered. You can use React Hooks to achieve this like below (not tested, use as hint)

```
const ListIng = props => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);  // Initial data will be empty array
    props.list.map((item) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/ingredient/' + item)
        .then(response => {
            setData(e => ([...e, response.data.name]));  // On each response - populate array with new data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
    // Display resulting array as data comes
    return <div>{data.map(d => ({<p>{d}</p>}))}</div>
}
```